# Project including multiple Dockerfiles and apps sharing some files. How to construct it?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a project including multiple Dockerfiles.

The tree is like,

```
.
├── app1
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── app.py
│   └── huge_modules/
├── app2
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── app.py
│   └── huge_modules/
├── common
│   └── my_lib.py
└── deploy.sh
```

To build my application, common/ is necessary and we have to COPY it inside Dockerfile.
However, Dockerfile cannot afford to COPY files from its parent directory.

To be precise, it is possible if we run `docker build` with `-f` option in the project root.
But I would not like to do this because the build context will be unnecessarily large.
When building app1, I don't like to include app2/huge_modules/ in the build context (the same as when building app2).

So, I prepare a build script in each app directory.
Like this.

```sh
cd $(dirname $0)
cp ../common/* ./
docker build -t app1 .
```

But this solution seems ugly to me.
Is there a good solution for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a base image containing your `common` library, and then build your two app images on top of that. You'll probably end up restructuring things slightly to provide a Dockerfile for your common files:

```
.
├── app1
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── app.py
│   └── huge_modules/
├── app2
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── app.py
│   └── huge_modules/
├── base
|   ├── Dockerfile
|   └── common
│       └── my_lib.py
└── deploy.sh
```

You start by building a base image:

```
docker build -t mybaseimage base/
```

And then your Dockerfile for app1 and app2 would start with:

```
FROM mybaseimage
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to start the build process from the top directory, with the -f flag you mentioned, dynamically generating the .dockerignore file.

That is, lets say that you currently build app1. Then you would first create in the top directory a .dockerignore file with the content: `app2`, then run the build process. After finishing the build, remove the .dockerignore file.

Now you want to build app2? No problem! Similarly generate first dynamically a .dockerignore file with the content `app1`, build and remove the file. Voila!

Comment: This could be a good solution. But in my case, it is hard to generate dynamically .dockerignore before build. Actually, build is done by a framework, with which we can only specify Dockerfile location and build location.

Comment: What framework is it? Would it be possible to specify prebuild hook?